# Understanding Stratified sampling in numpy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, statistics

I am currently completing an exercise book on machine learning to wet my feet so to speak in the discipline. Right now I am working on a real estate data set: each instance is a district of california and has several attributes, including the district's median income, which has been scaled and capped at 15. The median income histogram reveals that most median income values are clustered around 2 to 5, but some values go far beyond 6. The author wants to use stratified sampling, basing the strata on the median income value. He offers the next piece of code to create an income category attribute.

```
housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["median_income"] / 1.5)
housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"] < 5, 5.0, inplace=True)
```

He explains that he divides the median_income by 1.5 to limit the number of categories and that he then keeps only those categories lower than 5 and merges all other categories into category 5.

What I don't understand is

- Why is it mathematically sound to divide the median_income of each instance to create the strata? What exactly does the result of this division mean? Are there other ways to calculate/limit the number of strata?
- How does the division restrict the number of categories and why did he choose 1.5 as the divisor instead of a different value? How did he know which value to pick?
- Why does he only want 5 categories and how did he know beforehand that there would be at least 5 categories?

Any help understanding these decisions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm also not sure if this is the StackOverFlow category I should post this question in, so if I made a mistake by doing so please let me know what might be the appropriate forum.

Thank you!

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You may be the right person to analyze more on this based on your data set. But I can help you understanding stratified sampling, so that you will have an idea.

STRATIFIED SAMPLING: suppose you have a data set with consumers who eat different fruits. One feature is 'fruit type' and this feature has 10 different categories(apple,orange,grapes..etc) now if you just sample the data from data set, there is a possibility that sample data might not cover all the categories. Which is very bad when train the data. To avoid such scenario, we have a method called stratified sampling, in this probability of sampling each different category is same so that we will not miss any useful data.

Please let me know if you still have any questions, I would be very happy to help you.